# Bottom-first scrolling in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swiftui, swiftui-list

How can I make a SwiftUI `List` start scrolling from the bottom of the screen (like a chat view)?

Ideally, I want to mimic, e.g. the behavior of iMessage when the list updates, meaning it shifts down if an item is added when the user is at the bottom, but holds it’s position if the user manually scrolled up.

The list is read directly from a binding array, and the order can be reversed if convenient.

> @komal pointed out that the `UITableView` (the backend of `List`) has an `atScrollPosition` that should provide this functionality. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to access the underlying view without completely reimplementing `List` as a `UIViewRepresentable`, which is easier said than done, considering the standard implementation is completely black-boxed and closed-source.
>
> With that said, I've also posted [Access underlying UITableView from SwiftUI List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117712/access-underlying-uitableview-from-swiftui-list), which, if solved, could serve as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that instead of using scrollview, use UITableView as Tablview inherits scroll property of UIScrollview. And you can use "atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom" to achieve this behavior.

Comment: Is there a way to get the `List` to do this? (E.g. somehow access the base UITableView when the view appears?)

Comment: I've edited my question to reflect where I currently am.

Comment: I've filed a feedback requesting support for this with the SwiftUI List.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this way of inverting a `ScrollView`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let degreesToFlip: Double = 180

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Number: \(i)")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(self.degreesToFlip))
            }
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(self.degreesToFlip))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that you inverse everything in the `ScrollView` so you inverse the content also but the scroll indicator also gets reversed so instead of being on the right side the indicator is now on the left side. Maybe there is some configuration to always have the indicator on the right side.

Note that I have disabled the scroll indicator in this example code and that this also applies on `List` but in lists I didn't find any ways to hide the scroll indicator.

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Using UITableView.appearance().showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false is working fine for me on iOS 14.