# Access underlying UITableView from SwiftUI List

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swiftui, swiftui-list

Using a `List` view, is there a way to access (and therefore modify) the underlying `UITableView` object without reimplementing the entire `List` as a `UIViewRepresentable`?

I've tried initializing a `List` within my own `UIViewRepresentable`, but I can't seem to get SwiftUI to initialize the view when I need it to, and I just get an empty basic `UIView` with no subviews.

This question is to help find an answer for [Bottom-first scrolling in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58101865/bottom-first-scrolling-in-swiftui).

---

Alternatively, a library or other project that reimplements `UITableView` in SwiftUI would also answer this question.

Comment: As you've discovered, SwiftUI isn't fit for purpose yet. It's fine for producing a few demo screens, but to build anything approaching a full featured app, for now, you'll need to continue using UIKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is no.** As of iOS 13, SwiftUI's List is not currently designed to replace all the functionality and customizability of UITableView. It is designed to meet the most basic use of a UITableView: a standard looking, scrollable, editable list where you can place a relatively simply view in each cell.

In other words, you are giving up customizability for the simplicity of having swipes, navigation, moves, deletes, etc. automatically implemented for you.

I'm sure that as SwiftUI evolves, List (or an equivalent view) will get more customizable, and we'll be able to do things like scroll from the bottom, change padding, etc. The best way to make sure this happens is to [file feedback suggestions with Apple](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com). I'm sure the SwiftUI engineers are already hard at work designing the features that will appear at WWDC 2020. The more input they have to guide what the community wants and needs, the better.

Comment: I've filed a feedback requesting this feature, or alternatively adding a documented way to implement custom ListStyles that can modify the UITableView directly.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. Or was correct when marked. You can easily access the underlying UIKit components from SwiftUI view. For instance, SwiftUI List is built on top of UITableView. There's an Introspect library that does show you how to access and customise the underlying UIKit view. Find the link in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61054760/3849039

Answer (score 6):

The answer is Yes. There's an amazing library that lets you inspect the underlying UIKit views. Here's a [link](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) to it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a library called `Rotoscope` [on GitHub](https://github.com/noppefoxwolf/Rotoscope) (I am not the author of this).

This library is used to implement `RefreshUI` [also on GitHub](https://github.com/noppefoxwolf/RefreshUI) by the same author.

How it works is that `Rotoscope` has a `tagging` method, which overlays a 0 sized `UIViewRepresentable` on top of your `List` (so it's invisible). The view will dig through the chain of views and eventually find the `UIHostingView` that's hosting the SwiftUI views. Then, it will return the first subview of the hosting view, which should contains a wrapper of `UITableView`, then you can access the table view object by getting the subview of the wrapper.

The `RefreshUI` library uses this library to implement a refresh control to the SwiftUI `List` (you can go into the GitHub link and check out the source to see how it's implemented).

However, I see this more like a hack than an actual method, so it's up to you to decide whether you want to use this or not. There are no guarantee that it will continue working between major updates as Apple could change the internal view layout and this library will break.

Answer (score 1):

You can Do it. But it requires a Hack.

1. Add Any custom UIView
2. Use UIResponder to backtrack until you find table View.
3. Modify UITableView The way you like.

Code Example of Adding Pull to refresh:

```
//1: create a custom view 
final class UIKitView : UIViewRepresentable {
    let callback: (UITableView) -> Void

    init(leafViewCB: @escaping ((UITableView) -> Void)) {
        callback = leafViewCB
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView  {
        let view = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude,
                                             y: CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude,
                                             width: CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude,
                                             height: CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude))
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        if let superView = uiView.superview {
            superView.backgroundColor = uiView.backgroundColor
        }

        if let tableView = uiView.next(UITableView.self) {
            callback(tableView)
        }
    }
}

extension UIResponder {
    func next<T: UIResponder>(_ type: T.Type) -> T? {
        return next as? T ?? next?.next(type)
    }
}

////Use:

struct Result: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var value: String
}


class RefreshableObject: ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var items: [Result] = [Result(value: "Binding"),
                                      Result(value: "ObservableObject"),
                                      Result(value: "Published")]

    let refreshControl: UIRefreshControl

    init() {
        refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action:
            #selector(self.handleRefreshControl),
                                      for: .valueChanged)
    }

    @objc func handleRefreshControl(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
           DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {  [weak self] in
                sender.endRefreshing()
                self?.items = [Result(value:"new"), Result(value:"data"), Result(value:"after"), Result(value:"refresh")]
           }
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var refreshableObject = RefreshableObject()
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    Section(footer: UIKitView.init { (tableView) in
                        if tableView.refreshControl == nil  {
                           tableView.refreshControl = self.refreshableObject.refreshControl
                        }
                    }){
                        ForEach(refreshableObject.items) { result in
                            Text(result.value)
                        }
                    }

                }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Nav bar")

            }
    }
}
```

Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 1):

To update from refresh action, binding **isUpdateOrdered** is being used.

*this code is based on code I found in web, couldn't find the author*

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class Model: ObservableObject{
    @Published var isUpdateOrdered = false{
        didSet{
            if isUpdateOrdered{
                update()
                isUpdateOrdered = false
                print("we got him!")
            }
        }
    }
    var random = 0
    @Published var arr = [Int]()
    
    func update(){
        isUpdateOrdered = false
        //your update code.... maybe some fetch request or POST?
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            LegacyScrollViewWithRefresh(isUpdateOrdered: $model.isUpdateOrdered) {
                VStack{
                    if model.arr.isEmpty{ 
//this is important to fill the
//scrollView with invisible data,
//in other case scroll won't work
//because of the constraints.
//You may get rid of them if you like. 
                        Text("refresh!")
                        ForEach(1..<100){ _ in
                            Text("")
                        }
                    }else{
                        ForEach(model.arr, id:\.self){ i in
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text(String(i)), label: { Text("Click me") })
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }.environmentObject(model)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct LegacyScrollViewWithRefresh: UIViewRepresentable {
    enum Action {
        case idle
        case offset(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, animated: Bool)
    }
    typealias Context = UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>
    @Binding var action: Action
    @Binding var isUpdateOrdered: Bool
    private let uiScrollView: UIScrollView
    private var uiRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    
    init<Content: View>(isUpdateOrdered: Binding<Bool>, content: Content) {
        let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: content)
        hosting.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self._isUpdateOrdered = isUpdateOrdered
        uiScrollView = UIScrollView()
        
        uiScrollView.addSubview(hosting.view)
        
        let constraints = [
            hosting.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiScrollView.leadingAnchor),
            hosting.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiScrollView.trailingAnchor),
            hosting.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            hosting.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            hosting.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiScrollView.widthAnchor)
        ]
        uiScrollView.addConstraints(constraints)
        
        self._action = Binding.constant(Action.idle)
    }
    
    init<Content: View>(isUpdateOrdered: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.init(isUpdateOrdered: isUpdateOrdered, content: content())
    }
    
    init<Content: View>(isUpdateOrdered: Binding<Bool>, action: Binding<Action>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.init(isUpdateOrdered: isUpdateOrdered, content: content())
        self._action = action
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        
        
        uiScrollView.addSubview(uiRefreshControl)
        uiRefreshControl.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handleRefreshControl(arguments:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return uiScrollView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        switch self.action {
            case .offset(let x, let y, let animated):
                uiView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: x, y: y), animated: animated)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.action = .idle
                }
            default:
                break
        }
    }
    
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        let legacyScrollView: LegacyScrollViewWithRefresh
        
        init(_ legacyScrollView: LegacyScrollViewWithRefresh) {
            self.legacyScrollView = legacyScrollView
        }
        @objc func handleRefreshControl(arguments: UIRefreshControl){
            print("refreshing")
            self.legacyScrollView.isUpdateOrdered = true
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2){
                arguments.endRefreshing()
//refresh animation will
//always be shown for 2 seconds,
//you may connect this behaviour
//to your update completion
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Somehow after trying everything, this solutions worked for me, tested under iOS 15.4 and 16. Is frustrating to know that Apple does not have a more "Swifty" way to handle UIRefreshController (like a modifier)

Answer (score -1):

There is currently no way to access or modify the underlying UITableView

Comment: Modifying is possible. Just customize the UITableView in the init method of the SwiftUI ContentView struct. Accessing is possible. There are two libraries which already do that: https://github.com/noppefoxwolf/Rotoscope and https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect